# Compare a date range from a table with another table date range and find missing period

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Please find below input and required output. i need a query/procedure/function in T-SQL to get this output.

Requirement: I have table a and table b.

1. get all the date ranges from table b and missing date ranges from table a (when compared with table b).
2. Basically we need to make sure all the date ranges in table a, need to be covered in the output

---

```
Input       
table b

Start date  End date    ID
1/1/2009    9/30/2009   1
1/1/2013    9/30/2013   1
11/1/2014   11/30/2014  1
2/2/2015    12/31/2016  1

table a 
1/1/2009    12/31/2011  1
1/1/2013    9/30/2013   1
1/1/2014    4/30/2014   1
10/1/2014   12/31/2014  1
2/2/2015    12/31/9999  1
```

---

```
Output      
table b

Start date  End date    ID
1/1/2009    9/30/2009   1
1/1/2013    9/30/2013   1
11/1/2014   11/30/2014  1
2/2/2015    12/31/2016  1

table a         
10/1/2009   12/31/2011  1
1/1/2014    4/30/2014   1
10/1/2014   10/31/2014  1
12/1/2014   12/31/2014  1
1/1/2017    12/31/9999  1
```

Comment: Could you post your sample data as table with inserts? The formatting here is challenging and honestly the first thing anybody is going to do is move this to a table.

Comment: This article might be a very good starting point for you: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: What is your expected output? You shown table a and b, both are output tables?

Comment: Please include details of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Table [a] contain 4 records and table[b] contain 5 records. And you need that 5th record to be inserted into table [b]. If this is correct then...
Do simple outer join on table [a] and [b] on start data and end data. Get the value from table [a] where you find respective row NULL in table [b]

seems simple as it is :-)

Happy coding!!!